# Add email attachments by URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

I tried this code to attach a file in CI. This is working:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('me@mymail.com', 'vignesh');
$this->email->subject('Email Test with attachment');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class IN CODEIGNITER');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/attachment1.jpg');
$this->email->send();
```

But I want to attach a file from an external URL:

```
$this->email->attach('http://mydomain.in/path/to/attachment1.jpg');
```

Comment: NP, but it was actually originally stealthyninja's edit. I just reworded his edit a little and then approved the change. ;-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't possible, you'll need to download the file first. Using Phil Sturgeon's [cURL library](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl) for CodeIgniter you should be able to get the file

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$img = $this->curl->simple_get('http://mydomain.in/path/to/attachment1.jpg');
$filename = basename($img);
write_file("./upload/path/" . $filename, $img);
```

and then include it

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/attachment1.jpg');
```

You could later build in caching to check if the file was already downloaded / exists so it doesn't need to fetch it again.